# duoconnect not opening browser - Ubuntu 20.04 windows linux subsystem

Tags: ssh, gitlab, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I'm trying to clone repo from the gitlab. I've already added the ssh keys in my account.
What's supposed to happen when I clone via ssh is that the browser will open for authentication via duoconnect. I've already installed duoconnect on my wsl & windows too. I've installed wslu package also for the browser. But the browser doesn't open for authentication. It works fine on my windows but doesn't work on my linux subsytem.

This is my **config**:

```
Host <server>
    HostName <server>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host <server>
        ProxyCommand duoconnect -host=%h:%p -relay=<server>
```

I followed these
[duo connect guide on linux](https://guide.duo.com/duoconnect#linux)

Answer (score 0):

> But the browser doesn't open for authentication.

As seen in "[Open browser in host system from Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://superuser.com/a/1765001/141)", check first if `xdg-open` (or [`wslview`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667072/7490), from [`wslutilities/wslu`](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu)) manages to launch/open the browser.

If that works, then you can enable [debug logging for DuoConnect](https://help.duo.com/s/article/6852?language=en_US) and see if the WSL environment is interfering with the proper execution of that network gateway.

Comment: `xdg-open` manages to launch my browser

when i try to run this manually on the terminal `duoconnect -host=%h:%p -relay=<server> -log ~/duoconnect.log`, it opens the browser and logs, it's the same with `ssh -v <server>`
but when I git clone the repo using ssh, it fails to open the browser and there's a connection timeout, it also doesn't log anything @vonc @VonC

Comment: @zerotwo Strange. Beside checking logs and system messages, I don't have other ideas for now.